# What is the correct syntax for @pin in the new method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know that the correct syntax for `@pin` in `create` method is

`@pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)`, but I'm just not 100% sure which syntax to use in `new` method since it is just for initialization.

is it?

```
def new
  @pin = Pin.new
end
```

or is it?

```
def new
  @pin = current_user.pins.build
end
```

Comment: I believe there is an error in your code. It should be `@pin = current_user.pins.create(pin_params)`

Comment: Nope. It should be `.build`

Comment: Build doesn't create record in a database

Comment: I know, that's why there's a `create` method inside the controller which handles the saving through the code `if @pin.save`

Comment: ok, sorry then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the second one because it will set the user_id automatically

Answer (score 0):

It's dependent will you use `@pin.user` variable in your form or not?

Probably you can use in your form `@pin.user.name`.
The common wrong pattern is creating `hidden_field` for `user_id` column because it's not secured.

Comment: Did you mean views when you mention form?

Comment: Yes, `form` in a view for `new` action.

Comment: I just don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Both are ok to use. There no best practice *(at least non I know of)* for this. 
It is more a matter of preference. I would choose former variant as it is easier to read *for me*.

Note, however, that the result of two lines is different.
The second line is equvalient to:

`Pin.new(user: current_user)`